# How do I make a new terminal window use a new version of nano installed with homebrew?

Tags: command-line, homebrew

MacBook Air M1, MacOs Monterey

I have installed with homebrew the latest version (6.1) of the nano editor, which I can start with `nano`.
However, in a new terminal window, `nano` launches the old, pre-installed version (2.0.1).

How can I permanently disable or uninstall the old version to make sure that only the new version is used?

Comment: How does your PATH look like?

Comment: /Users/<username>/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/<username>/.cargo/bin

Answer (score -1):

Reboot helps.

After a full restart of the Mac, the issue is gone.

Comment: That should not be needed

Comment: but it solved the issue, i cannot reproduce it any more